# How Use Module.Export Variable Async/Await on the NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, async-await

app.js

```
module.exports = {
    IO: io,
    SETTINGS: SETTINGS,
    _ADMINSOCKETIDS: sys._TEMP._ADMINSOCKETIDS
}
```

func.js

```
let io = false;
setTimeout(function () {
    io =  require('../app.js').IO;
    console.log(io); // works
},300);

function emitUser(socketId,text){
    io.to(socketId).emit('sayHello', {data:text});
}
```

how would be possible that turn it  async system, module.export & require

i must wait variable io from app.js for use in func.js module

Comment: Assign to `module.exports.IO`, instead of your local `io` variable - the exports property is not a getter or alias. On the other hand, that's useless as anyone who imports your module won't know when the value changes. So instead of having a boolean `IO` export, export a promise for the value.

Comment: io = false;
i am using that for  
if(io) io.to(socketId).emit()

Comment: So you actually want to export `emitUser` instead of `io`, and have it fail silently when the initialisation isn't done yet?